# Rest API - ошибка "400 Bad Request" с запросом @PUT

Tags: java, rest, put, http-status-code-400

При выполнении [примера](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/basic_grizzly_jersey/jersey-grizzly-json-service.html#section6) с Rest API c сайта Oracle, при запросе `@PUT` выпадает ошибка :

> Can not construct instance of java.util.UUID from String value '3136':
>   not a valid textual representation, problem: UUID has to be
>   represented by the standard 36-char rep  resentation   at [Source:
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@628b3b;
>   line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: Note["id"])

Вот сам код:

Note.java

```
public class Note {
    private final UUID id;
    private final String title;

    private Note(NoteBuilder builder){
        this.id = builder.id;
        this.title = builder.title;
    }

    public Note(){
        Note not = new Note.NoteBuilder().id().build();
        this.id = not.getId();
        this.title = not.getTitle();
    }

    public Note(UUID id, String title) {
        Note not = new Note.NoteBuilder().id()
                .title(title)
                .build();

        this.id = not.getId();
        this.title = not.getTitle();
    }

    public UUID getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "ID: " + id
                + " Title: " + title;
    }

    public static class NoteBuilder{
        private UUID id;
        private String title = "";

        public NoteBuilder id(){
            this.id =  UUID.randomUUID();
            return this;
        }

        public NoteBuilder title(String title){
            this.title = title;
            return this;
        }

        public Note build(){
            return new Note(this);
        }
    }
}
```

NoteList.java

```
public class NoteList {
    private static final CopyOnWriteArrayList<Note> nList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    static {
        nList.add(
                new Note.NoteBuilder().id()
                        .title("1 заметка")
                        .build()
        );

        nList.add(
                new Note.NoteBuilder().id()
                        .title("2 заметка")
                        .build()
        );
    }
    private NoteList() {
    }

    public static CopyOnWriteArrayList<Note> getInstance(){
            return nList;
        }
}
```

NoteService.java

```
@Path("/notes")
public class NoteService {

    private final CopyOnWriteArrayList<Note> nList = NoteList.getInstance();

    @GET
    @Path("/all")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getAll(){
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(nList);
    }

    @POST 
    @Path("/add")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response addNote(Note note){
        nList.add(note);
        return Response.status(201).build();
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/remove/{id}")
    public Response deleteNote(@PathParam("id") UUID id){
        Predicate<Note> note = n -> n.getId().equals(id);
        if (nList.removeIf(note)) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
        }else {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
        }

    }

   @PUT
   @Path("{id}/update") 
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
   public Response updateNote(Note note){ 
       int matchIdx = 0; 
       Optional<Note> match = nList.stream() 
      .filter(n -> n.getId().equals(note.getId())) 
      .findFirst(); 
      if (match.isPresent()) { 
         matchIdx = nList.indexOf(match.get()); 
         nList.set(matchIdx, note); 
         return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build(); 
      } else { 
         return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build(); 
        } 
   }
```

При запросе `@GET` выводится следующее:

> [{"id": "313695e0-72a5-4aab-9047-fbec516dab4f", "title":"1 заметка",
>   "id": "9e4b9d09-347b-439c-aecf-b259b086f987","title":"2 заметка"}]

Правда почему то в не в виде дерева. Но тем не менее, это всё равно объект `JSON`, как я понимаю.

Запрос `@PUT` подаю через [сURL](https://curl.haxx.se/) в таком виде:

```
curl -X PUT -i -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"id\":313695e0-72a5-4aab-9047-fbec516dab4f,\"title\":\"новая заметка\"}" http://localhost:8080/test_war_exploded/notes/313695e0-72a5-4aab-9047-fbec516dab4f/update
```

Сервер выдаёт

> 400 Bad Request

, т.е. была синтаксическая ошибка в запросе. Пытается создать объект UUID из первых четырёх цифр моего id в виде String. Причём здесь String собственно? Почему система преобразовывает из UUID в String. Или надо как-то по-другому писать запрос?

Comment: Забыли вокруг UUID кавычки поставить.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev в запросе на этом участке `"{\"id\":313695e0-...`? У оракла там кавычек нет, правда у них id типа int, а у меня объект UUID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В JSON нет такого типа UUID. [JSON на википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

Соответсвенно вы должны передать строку, а строка уже будет распарсена сервером как UUID. Строки в JSON пишутся в кавычках. А вы написали без. Поэтому строка пытается распознаться как число; так как дальше идут буквы, то распознались только числа перед первой буквой (в вашем случае перед e0 идет 31369).

Дальше пытаемся распарсить UUID из строки 31369, так как это не строка, а число ты преобразовываем в строку и получаем ошибку `Can not construct instance of java.util.UUID from String value '3136'`

Исправляется просто добавлением кавычек:

`-d "{\"id\":\"313695e0-72a5-4aab-9047-fbec516dab4f\" ...`

Хотя очень странно. Перед e0 идет 313695, е не 3136, но все же я думаю проблема в кавычках )

Comment: да-да, число должно быть 313695, я просто взял старое из буфера